# Binding partial to multiple actionresults

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if anybody could suggest a way of overcoming the following issue. I have the following models

```
    // AModel
    public class AModel
    {
        public string PropOne { get; set; }
        public bool PropTwo { get; set; }
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
    }

    public class AModelViewModel
    {
        public AModelViewModel()
        {
            AModel = new AModel();
        }

        public AModel AModel { get; set; }
    }

    //BModel
    public class BModel
    {
        public string PropOne { get; set; }
        public bool PropTwo { get; set; }
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
    }

    public class BModelViewModel
    {
        public BModelViewModel()
        {
            BModel = new BModel();
        }

        public BModel BModel { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what my controller looks like

```
    public ActionResult PageA()
    {
        var model = new AModelViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PageA(AModel aModel)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PageB()
    {
        var model = new BModelViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PageB(BModel bModel)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The two views look like this

```
//PageA
@model WebApplication13.Models.AModelViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="title" class="form-control" id="title" name="Model.PropOne">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Model.PropTwo)
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_RandomView.cshtml")

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}


//PageB
@model WebApplication13.Models.BModelViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="title" class="form-control" id="title" name="Model.PropOne">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Model.PropTwo)
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_RandomView.cshtml")

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
```

Both views use the following partial view

```
//_RandomView
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="keyword">Keyword</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Keyword" />
</div>
```

The problem I have is that because this partial is shared, and the name attribute of the keyword input is 'Keyword', when I submit the form on either page the keyword property is never binded so it's always null. Is there a way I can share this partial, but alter the prefix depending on what page i'm using. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have two different models with exactly smae properties. Just create one model and one viewmodel. A viewModel can serve mulitple view.

Comment: @CodeNotFound. I should have pointed out that these models are not supposed to represent real models. I've just created them to try and display the problem I have.

Comment: You could try passing keyword through the ViewBag instead of having it be a bound property.  That's always pretty easy.

in controller: ViewBag.Whatevername = whatever;  Then in view, you can display ViewBag.Whatevername.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a paritial view.. Create an EditorTemplate in Views\Shared\EditorTemplates named Keyword.cshtml with code something like

```
@model string
//_RandomView
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="keyword">Keyword</label>
    @Hmlt.TextBoxFor(a => a, new {class="form-control"})
</div>
```

then in your views you just call

```
@Html.EditorFor(a => a.AModel.Keyword,"Keyword")
```

if you have to use PartialView.. you can pass in an HtmlFieldPrefix via ViewDataDictionary when you call the partial view.  To do this, you would call your partial like this.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_RandomView.cshtml", 
                 new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() {
                       HtmlFieldPrefix = "AModel" } });
```

then in your partial view you will need to use the @Html.Textbox helper like so.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="keyword">Keyword</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Keyword", string.Empty, new { @class="form-control" })
</div>
```